# When should I use a factory to wrap a constructor in Perl?

Tags: perl, constructor, factory

Why to use factory to wrap a constructor in Perl? An example would help.

Comment: Hey kivien, you seem to be new here... may I suggest you read http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html before asking more questions?

Comment: I think it's a fine question. It's one of those philosophical, high-level ones rather than a "solve my immediate problem urgent urgent" types.

Comment: @brian - I must disagree. As far as Perl questions go, it's useless. If you disagree, then to prove me wrong, please perform the following mental experiment. If, in the space of the next hour, I post 200-1000 questions in a matrix of "When should I use a $pattern in $language", would you feel compelled to upvote all 200 or at least argue that they should all be upvoted even if you don't have time to do so yourself? If not, this question is not deserving of upvote either.

Comment: If this was just an extremely poor way of asking "what would be the use case for using pattern X", I'm 99% certain it'd be a dupe.

Comment: The only way this would have been a question worth being on SO would be "I see XYZ as use cases for factory pattern, but Perl natively provides ABC methods for solving that use case instead of factory. Does it mean factory pattern has no use case in Perl"? Or, less intelligently, at least ask "Is there any Perl specific use case of factory pattern?" Based on other posting by OP, it's more likely a homework Q, and not a deep philosophical question about meaning of life, universe and globs.

Comment: You thought it was a worthy enough question to answer it. *shrug*. Here's the answer to your mental experiment though. the difference between posting hundreds of questions and the one question from this new user is that he actually wants an answer, and you just want to be a jerk about it.

Comment: brian - you're contradicting yourself, sorry. Either the question is fine - but then so are 100s more in the experiment which are ABSOLUTELY IDENTICAL as far as their contribution to StackOverflow community. IIRC the whole idea of up/down votes was supposed to be related to the quality of the Q or A, NOT the **percieved** intent of the poster. ...

Comment: ...Or, you judge the question in relation to other behavior by the same user; and based on this user's set of questions, his intent is "do my homework for me and I don't want to bother with the bare minimum of asking properly, never mind doing bare modicum of prep work - and please don't blame it on ESL.

Comment: As far as my answer, I'd rather prefer this question to be deleted - BUT, as long as it exists, other people reading this deserve to know what the answer is even if the question is subpar.

Comment: BTW, "to be a jerk" is a bit uncalled for, sorry. The logic behind the experiment is "if the most helpful/experienced/respected member of SO Perl community thinks that the question X - which is Perl agnostic - is a fine deep philosophical question, then by inference that questions ought to be just as helpful for other languages.

Comment: FwIW, I posted my original comment in response to the pattern of the multiple questions I saw from this poster, not specifically due to just this one.

Comment: @DVK: if you don't like this question, just ignore it and move on in life. Surely you have better ways to spend your time. I thought the question was fine, said so, and answered it.

Answer (score 5):

Same exact reason you'd use a factory in any other OO language.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

> Factory methods are common in toolkits and frameworks where library code
>   needs to create objects of types which may be subclassed by applications
>   using the framework.
>
> Parallel class hierarchies often
>   require objects from one hierarchy to
>   be able to create appropriate objects
>   from another.
>
> Factory methods are used in
>   test-driven development to allow
>   classes to be put under test[2]. If
>   such a class Foo creates another
>   object Dangerous that can't be put
>   under automated unit tests (perhaps it
>   communicates with a production
>   database that isn't always available),
>   then the creation of Dangerous objects
>   is placed in the virtual factory
>   method createDangerous in class Foo.
>   For testing, TestFoo (a subclass of
>   Foo) is then created, with the virtual
>   factory method createDangerous
>   overridden to create and return
>   FakeDangerous, a fake object. Unit
>   tests then use TestFoo to test the
>   functionality of Foo without incurring
>   the side effect of using a real
>   Dangerous object.

Further details on Perl factory pattern:

http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2003/08/15/design3.html

and

http://www.perldesignpatterns.com/?FactoryObject

Answer (score 5):

A common use of a Factory is to produce a object when you don't know which type you'll need ahead of time. The factory figures out which constructor to call based on the situation.

Just as an example, let's say you want to make a class to download files, but you don't know ahead of time how you can fetch a file. Maybe it's FTP, HTTP, SVN, or something else. You have a Downloader class that takes a URL of any type and gives you an object:

```
 my $object = Downloader->new( $some_url );
```

You don't know the type of this object, but you don't care either. All the objects it creates know how to respond to `store_in_directory`, so you call the method without knowing the type of the particular object:

```
 $object->store_in_directory( $dir );
```

And there you go. The `new` factory let subclasses (or something else) create `$object`. It makes the interface simpler because at the application level you don't worry about choosing the right class.

One of the nice features about Perl is that you don't have to hardcode class names. You can do something like this, where you use a string defined at runtime to build the object:

```
 sub new {
      my( $class, @args ) = @_;

      my $output_class = $class->choose_the_right_implementing_class;

      my $output_object = $output_class->new;
      }
```